# Showing the overlap between a sphere and the volume insdie a solid angle with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to describe how a line-of-sight integration of a 3D density function over a solid angle  means using the pgf/Tikz package. The problem  is to draw a sphere and then a solid angle that overlaps some part of the sphere. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the appropriate functions in the Tikz package for doing this job. Could you please help me by answering the following questions?

1. Is it possible to make the dashed lines look like being behind the sphere?
2. Is it also possible to make the volume inside the sphere and inside the solid angle darker than other regions?
3. Are there better tricks of using Tikz to do the visualization intended here?
   [image]

Here are the codes used to generate the image.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
%set the plot display orientation
%synatax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
%\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{110}
 
% Define variables and assign values to them.
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{0.9}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\shade[ball color = white] (1.8,1.5) circle (\rvec);

%Define a point.
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\tdplotsetcoord{P1}{4}{90}{25}
\tdplotsetcoord{P2}{4}{90}{30}
\tdplotsetcoord{P3}{4}{83}{25}
\tdplotsetcoord{P4}{4}{83}{30}

\draw [-stealth, very thin, dashed] (O) -- (P1);
\draw [-stealth, very thin, dashed] (O) -- (P2);
\draw [-stealth, very thin, dashed] (O) -- (P3);
\draw [-stealth, very thin, dashed] (O) -- (P4);

\draw [thin] (P1) arc (25:30:4);
\draw [thin] (P3) arc (25:30:4);
\draw [thin] (P1) -- (P3);
\draw [thin] (P2) -- (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you move the sphere-drawing code below the code drawing the dashed lines it'll be infront of those and hence cover them.

Comment: You need to specify where the sphere is located in 3d. Then you can compute the intersections of the dashed lines with the sphere and use those intersections to draw them correctly. (The arcs are also arcs in 2d, but you need 3d arcs. `tikz-3dplot` has macros for those.)

Comment: @anonymous Thank you for your comment! In the internet I saw may examples of drawing the sphere and arc only using 2D coordinates but not 3D coordinates. Could you please tell me which commands I can use, or point me to an example?

Comment: First of all, you do not install an orthographic view in your present code. In order to really make use of `tikz-3dplot` you need to set the view angles e.g. with `\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{110}` and then use the key `tdplot_main_coords` in the options of the picture or some scope. However, to draw the sphere you need to locally install `tdplot_main_coords`. Finally, arcs can be drawn with `\tdplotdrawarc` (see the manual) or parametric plots.